# How to get all the top(max) months base on the count of each month in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get all the top (max) months base on the count of each month in one column:

```
month

Oct
Oct
Oct
Jan
Jan
Jan
Feb
Feb
Aug
```

in this case, Oct and Jan are both top months with 3 counts.

With below code, I can only get one of the top months. How can I get the output for all the top months (Oct and Jan) instead of only Oct or Jan? The problem is I am not sure how to detect how many months with same max count.

```
top_month = df.groupby('month')['month'].count().sort_values().tail(1).index.values[0]
```

This output I want is:

```
Top month: Oct, Jan
```

Comment: You are looking for [`mode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html#pandas.Series.mode)...

Comment: with mode(), I got something like this
```
0  Oct
1  Jan
```
how can I I just get Oct and Jan?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? `mode` returns a `Series`. You can always just do `.mode().tolist()`